# I cannot find my alpha android project in play services list

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I created an android application in the google developer console and published it to alpha.

I went to setup google play services for an app, but I cannot find my alpha application in 'I already use Google APIs in my game'.

I can create a new project from 'I don't use any Google APIs in my game yet', but I hope I can use my alpha application if there is a way to do that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks for advance.

Comment: only  users in your test group  can view your alpha project on playstore.

Comment: So what Google APIs do you actually use in your currently published to Alpha application? These would be apps you manually set up in [the Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you. I am using unity with android google play plugin jar files embedded there. The plugin is there but I need to start setup of the google play services from the developer console to be able to get the ID and related stuff.